# How to connect to ms sql server on remote desktop( requires user login and password ) using java?

Tags: java, sql-server, remote-desktop

I'am making a tool which requires me to connect ms sql server on remote desktop connection . I have tried the establishing the connection but got stuck in figuring out the code for how to access remote desktop with user id and password . sample code for that particular part would very helpful

Comment: what do you mean by `connect ms sql server on remote desktop connection` ?

Comment: i want to connect my java application with ms sql server which is running on remote desktop connection

Comment: "Remote Desktop" typically refers to an application you use to remote control another computer. You can just say you need to connect to an instance of SQL Server that is installed on a remote server. Your code will depend on the adapter you use to connect to the SQL Server instance. You should post the code you're using to connect, but leave out the server name (or IP) and the username/password. Regardless of the adapter, the key to connecting is in your [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: `Remote Desktop Connection` is a client application. You mean the SQL Server is running on a remote server and your Java apps wants to connect to it via Remote Desktop Protocol ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Remote Desktop is a client application which you use to connect to the Windows Server on which your SQL Server resides. You do not need this in your code.

The following code will connect you to a SQL Server:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433","username", "password");
```

And if you want to query the SQL Server you can continue with:

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeQuery("select * from my_table");
```

I recommend you read some tutorials on JDBC such as [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-2017)